# Fill non-contiguous blank cells with the value from the cell above the first blank

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a column like the following:

```
1 red
2 blue
3 red
4 
5 blue
6
7
8 white
```

The blanks refer to the record above it. So #4 would be associated with red
and 6 and 7 would be blue.

Is there an easy way to fill in the blanks for entire column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Select `A1:A8`.
- Press `F5` to show the *Goto* dialog.
- Click *Special* .....  Select *Blanks* and click OK.

That will select a noncontiguous range of blank cells.

- Then, without selecting anything else, type `=A3` and press [control](/questions/tagged/control)+[enter](/questions/tagged/enter).
- That will enter an array formula in all the blank cells referring to the cell above it.
- Reselect `A1:A8`, and *Edit - Copy*.
- Then *Edit - Paste Special - Values*.  And you're all set.

Note that the `=A3` refers to the cell above the *first* blank cell.

If you want to do it with a macro, you could loop through the cells and fill in the empty ones.

```
Public Sub FillBlanks()

    Dim rColumn As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        For Each rColumn In Selection.Columns
            For Each rCell In rColumn.Cells
                If rCell.Row > rColumn.Cells(1).Row Then
                    If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
                        rCell.Value = rCell.Offset(-1).Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next rCell
        Next rColumn
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Very Slick - how can we do this with a Macro? using SendKeys "^{ENTER}"  ?

Comment: Beware not to select a whole column, like A:A or it will loop forever. Otherwise a real time saver!