# Vba code to replicate a particular value over a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to macros, please help me with the below requirements.

I have two columns in a sheet. The second column contains a set of dates for each value of first column. I want to drag the values in the first column until there are dates in the second column. There is a one line separation between different names in first column and second column.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want a way to auto populate the first column with respect to second column where there is date

Comment: And what have you tried so far? You are aware that SO is not a coding service? You have read the introduction to SO https://stackoverflow.com/tour?

Comment: Maybe a screendump can explain your question further?

Comment: what do you mean by `drag`?

Comment: `one line seperation between different names` does not mean anything familiar

Answer (score 0):

If you have two columns of data and want to replicate the values in the first down to the next value in the second, you don't need to use vba.

If I understand correctly, you have something similar to

```
+--------+-------+
| Value1 | Date1 |
+--------+-------+
|        |       |
+--------+-------+
|        |       |
+--------+-------+
| Value2 | Date2 |
+--------+-------+
```

Putting the formulae `=if(R[1]C[1]="",R[-1]C,"")` in the blank cells of column one will fill in each cell with `Value1` all the way down, leaving one blank row to the next data.

Like so:

```
+--------+-------+
| Value1 | Date1 |
+--------+-------+
| Value1 |       |
+--------+-------+
|        |       |
+--------+-------+
| Value2 | Date2 |
+--------+-------+
```

To fill in all of the needed cells use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17774204).

If this needs to be automated more, [VBA can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20439428) to fill in the blank rows with the formula.