# Fill in blank Excel cells using value from another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Similar to [Fill non-contiguous blank cells with the value from the cell above the first blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499167/fill-non-contiguous-blank-cells-with-the-value-from-the-cell-above-the-first-bla)
but using an adjacent column instead.

I have something like this:

[image]

For all the blank values in column A, I would like it to be populated with the matching value from column C.
So A2 would be populated with C2 and A4 with C4.

Comment: So what did not work? you would simply use the formula `=C2`instead of the one posted.

Comment: I have many many entries in document so I would like a way to do it automatically. Some cells already have values and others don't.

Comment: It's preferable to leave the table as text and not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new column. In Cell B2, write the formula `=IF(A2<>"",B2, D2)`. This will set A2 to be equal to the old value if there was an old value, or the corresponding value in column C (which was moved to D when you inserted a new column) if it was missing a value. Drag this formula down. Then, copy the column, paste > paste special > values only, and keep your new column. Then, delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

In a new column D, you can use the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(A4), C4, A4)` and that would output:

```
A   B   C   D
-------------
X   Y   Y   X
    G   R   R
e   9   T   e
    K   7   7
```