# A special kind of copy and paste I have not seen before. Do you know a code that could fill this in for 400+ clients?

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I need to copy paste a top row (not the header row) into 15 blank rows below itself and repeat through 400+ files.

```
Client Lookup   ER Name EE Lookup   EE Name Date
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/16/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/17/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/18/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/19/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/20/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/21/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/22/2018
7704    , Cheikh    902233  Mahmoud,    11/23/2018



7232    , Emmanuel  902157  , Victoria  11/16/2018
                                        11/17/2018
                                        11/18/2018
                                        11/19/2018
                                        11/20/2018
                                        11/21/2018
                                        11/22/2018
```

Can this be done in Excel? Columns "$A:$D" are absolute, while the rows are relative.

Can a macro or VBA save the day for this type of repetitive task? Is Excel limited with this type of copy paste?

Please, opinions, suggestions, ideas, codes, answers, responses are all welcomed here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fill non-contiguous blank cells with the value from the cell above the first blank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8499167/11683)

Comment: Thank you! This led me on a path that does it by column. Now, I need to see if a range can be set, so that it can fill multiple columns with one click instead of doing individual columns. You have taken me further than I was before. You are amazing!! Again, Thank you!

Comment: Good news! It turns out I did not need a code for the second half. I used the Go To Special and created a macro around my parameters. Thank you to all those who shared, I do not believe I could have completed this on my own. Thank you StackOverFlow for this platform that allowed me to reach out to the community! Together, we got it done! I look forward to coming back and seeing if I can assist someone else with their project. Best wishes ~I – I

Comment: mind share the solution here for the benefit of the future readers?( :

Comment: I did share the solution. I used the "Go To Special" in the Find tab and created a macro...steps are as follows.

Comment: I did share the solution. I used the "Go To Special" in the Find tab and created a macro...steps are as follows...1) click on Find. 2) click on Go To Special. 3) click on Blank Cells. 4) click OK. 5) type "=(up arrow)ctrl+enter" (This copies the above cell into the blank cells.) 6) hover mouse on right of selected box until the four arrow cursor appears, then right click-hold, drag over to the right and directly back again, when you release it, a pop up window will offer other options. Choose "Copy Values". (This gets rid of the formula in the blank cells.)  Record these steps.

Comment: I hope this helps. I am happy to assist others in any way that I can. Please let me know if more clarification is needed. :)  ~Irene