# New Column that removes blanks of previous column (FORMULA ONLY)

Tags: excel, formula

Is this possible using formulas?

A1 has Apple in it.  A5 has banana in it.  A9 has carrot.  There are spaces between A2-A4, A6-A8.  I want a new column (Starting at B1) to fill those blanks with val above. I have tried using offset and row numbers but can’t get it working so far.

[Excel sheet link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtoun1dijct1i7w/Removing%20spaces%20of%20previous%20Column.xlsx?dl=0)

[image: Image link here]

Column A or 1 represents what my data looks like in image/excel

Column B represents what I want it to do in image/excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Cell B1` enter following formula

```
=A1
```

Then in `Cell B2` enter the following formula

```
=IF(A2="",B1,A2)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

This can also be done without using formula. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3762765/6075259).

Comment: Thanks Mrig.  That worked.  I've been trying to get this working for ages